# term used to denote that code is rewritten?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Is there a term to describe when software programmers rewrite code for better efficiency, more throughput with less space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was actually looking for '[Code Refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Refactoring)' which while falling in the general manual program optimization part, I was looking for something more specific, as have shared.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you want "(manual) program optimization".

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization):

> In computer science, **program optimization** or **software optimization** is the process of modifying a software system to make some aspect of it work more efficiently or use fewer resources. In general, a computer program may be optimized so that it executes more rapidly, or is capable of operating with less memory storage or other resources, or draw less power.

"Manual", because it's done by the programmer, and not by a compiler (in which case it would be "automated").

Answer (score 1):

The term you ae looking for is

> [refactoring](https://www.refactoring.com)

thi is the commonly used term these days for rewriting code to improve it, longer ago the term might have been

> code rewrite